# Spring MVC RequestParam without name does not work on native image

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, parameters, graalvm, graalvm-native-image

Spring Boot 3.1.3
graalvm-jdk-17.0.8+9.1
native-maven-plugin 0.9.5

Controller methods without name in RequestParam does not work (below exception):

```
@GetMapping(value="/test", produces=MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE)
public String test(@RequestParam(required=false) String category)
```

Same with name to annotation works fine:

```
@GetMapping(value="/test", produces=MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE)
public String test(@RequestParam(name = "category", required=false) String category)
```

Exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Name for argument of type
[java.lang.String] not specified, and parameter name information notfound in class file either.
at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.updateNamedValueInfo(AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.java:177)
at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.getNamedValueInfo(AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.java:154)
at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.java:99)
```

cannot use spring boot as parent pom so importing it:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.3</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>import</scope>
</dependency>
```

pom fragment for native image generation, following [wiki](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/native-image.html#native-image.developing-your-first-application.buildpacks.maven) (tip):

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.graalvm.buildtools</groupId>
    <artifactId>native-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <fallback>false</fallback>
        <verbose>true</verbose>
        <quickBuild>true</quickBuild>
        <metadataRepository>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </metadataRepository>       
        <jvmArgs>
            <jvmArg>-XX:+UseContainerSupport</jvmArg>
            <jvmArg>-XX:MaxRAMPercentage=70</jvmArg>                                
        </jvmArgs>                          
        <buildArgs>
            <arg>-H:+ReportExceptionStackTraces</arg>
            <!-- WA for https://github.com/oracle/graal/issues/4757 -->
            <arg>-H:-UseContainerSupport</arg>
            <!-- Custom reachability metadata for 3rd parties, not yet supported in: https://github.com/oracle/graalvm-reachability-metadata/tree/master/metadata --> 
            <arg>-H:ReflectionConfigurationResources=META-INF/native-image/reflect-config.json</arg>
        </buildArgs>                            
        <requiredVersion>22.3</requiredVersion>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>add-reachability-metadata</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>add-reachability-metadata</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

When trying to add same method without name to [Demo](https://github.com/graalvm/graalvm-demos/tree/master/spring-native-image) application it works perfect, so I understand something is wrong with my project but cannot find the root cause.

```
@GetMapping(value="/test", produces=MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE)
public String test(@RequestParam(required=false) String category){
    System.out.println("category: " + category);
    return category;
}
```

Comment: When compiling you have to enable `-parameter` to retain the parameter information.

Comment: I'm using org.graalvm.buildtools:native-maven-plugin and cannot find "-parameter" in its buildArgs.

Comment: please add  your Maven `pom.xml` to the question.

Comment: I asked for th`pom.xml` not just any section. Why did you decide to configure the `native-maven-plugin` instead of going with the pre configured one from Spring BOot? Have you tried without the full configuration yuou have?

Comment: Updated the question to reply your concern, cannot put the entire pom as it is a big project which I'm trying to run on native image, so trying to figure out where is the root cause, on small demo project same works fine. I can try to inspect effective pom if someone can give a hint what to look for ?

Comment: Have you looked at the Spring Boot pre-configured `native-plugin-configuration`? The fact that you don't have the spring boot parent means you configured the maven-compiler plugin as well, make sure that that has `-parameters` as a build argument. Look at the spring boot parent pom to see how that configures those plugins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to M.Deinum comments, found the root cause after inspecting Spring Boot [parent pom](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/3.1.3/spring-boot-starter-parent-3.1.3.pom). Need to add parameters=true in maven-compiler-plugin to retain methods parameters name in compiled classes. However, it is probably better to fix the code and add parameters names to spring annotations to not increase final native image size by retaining these parameters names in compiled classes.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <parameters>true</parameters>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```